# Using fancyhdr, how to bump up minipage beneath line and more evenly extend line?

Tags: formatting

I have a resume that looks pretty good with exception to the header, and the header code is below. Basically, it's a name over a line, with address under the line on the left and contact info under the line on the right.

My problems are:
1) How do I get the line to go evenly all the way across the page? Now it just goes about 80% across the page. 
2) There's too much space from the line to first line of the address and contact info.  I'd like to bump that up to almost the line.
3) How to push the contact info further right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym} % latex symbol font
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Mr. Bojanglels}

\newgeometry{top=3cm,left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,bottom=2cm}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.4\textwidth}
\flushleft \footnotesize 1234 Maple Rd., Unit 1000 \\
Ville, Tx. 88088 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.4\textwidth}
bo@jangles.net \\
800-555-1212
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for a resume and you (probably) don't want this title heading on every page, so instead of using `fancyhdr`, I'm just manually creating a header.

I'm not sure you really want a rule that goes across the *whole* page since most printers will have a little bit at the end edge of the page that they can't print.  Having said that, I have offered both options in the code below, just (un)comment the appropriate one.

For the whitespace between paragraph, it can be set globally with `\setlength{\parskip}{<distance>}`.  You can also create a new paragraph with a given amount of whitespace with `\\[<distance>]`.

To get the contact details all the way to the right, I have used `\flushright` and also set both `minipage` environments to be `0.5\textwidth` so that contact details end up on the end.

Lastly, I have set `\parindent` to `0pt` since we (probably) don't want indented paragraphs in a resume.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  vmargin=2cm,
  hmargin=1.7cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
{\huge Mr.~Bojanglels} \\[-1ex]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \\[0.5ex]
% \centerline{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}} \\[0.5ex]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  1234 Maple Rd., Unit 1000 \\
  Ville, Tx. 88088 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \flushright
  bo@jangles.net \\
  800-555-1212
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I really like having to take out extra deps like fancyhdr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use vspace{-1.3cm} as the first line immediately after \begin{minipage} environment line. and change line number 16 as \newcolumntype{R}{p{.95\textwidth}} and compile you will get the desired result.

[image: alignedaddr]